# How to properly make nested fetch() calls in react component?

Tags: reactjs, http, github-api

So I have a react component that displays a users starred repositories on github along with open issues for those repos. In order to get the issues for the starred repos, I make a list of urls and then call Promise.all on a list of promises by mapping fetch to the list of urls. My state containing the starred repos is set on initial render, however the state for the issues is not. Any idea what is wrong with my code?

```
componentDidMount() {
// headers contain auth token for github api
let headers = new Headers() 
var myInit = {
  method: 'GET',
  headers: headers,
  mode: 'cors',
  cache: 'default'
};

fetch("https://api.github.com/users/djm158/starred", myInit)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(
  stars => {
      this.setState({
      stars: stars
    })

    let urls = []
    for (let i = 0; i < stars.length; i++) {
      urls.push(stars[i].url + '/issues')
    }

    return Promise.all(urls.map(url => fetch(url, myInit)))
  })
  .then(results => Promise.all(results.map(d => d.json())))
  .then(data => {
    this.setState({
      issues: data
    })
  })
```

}

Comment: Have you tried debugging it with a debugger?

Comment: I've stepped through the method using vscode's chrome debugger, disclaimer, not an expert in debugging react apps, this more of a personal project to learn. Haven't been able to piece together why setting the state for 'issues' isn't happening before mounting.

Comment: Found a fix, needed to check if the state was defined in the component's `render()` method and load placeholder html in the mean time.

Answer (score 0):

figured it out, here's a link to a working example of what I was trying to do https://github.com/djm158/github-starred-issues